# Python function with optional argument

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a function `multiples(n,upperLimit)` that returns a list with the multiples of a given number `n` less than or equal to `upperLimit`. What I want to do is make `upperLimit` an optional parameter with a default value of `10n` if the user does not specify any other value. How can I do this? I get an error that `n` hasn't been defined when I write `multiples(n,upperLimit=10*n)`. I'm running SageMath 9.1, which I believe is based on Python 3.x. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @RussJ I tried writing `upperLimit = 10*n`, but that didn't work. Is that normally how it's done?

Comment: You can’t refer to another parameter inside the parameter definitions. You can only do that inside the function. Set `upperLimit`’s default value to `None`, then check in the function if it `is None`, and if so, set it to `10 * n` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default values are evaluated when the function is defined, not when it's called. So they can't refer to other parameters, since the parameters don't have a value until the function is called.

Use `None` as the default, then check for this in the function.

```
def multiples(n, upperLimit = None):
    if upperLimit is None:
        upperLimit = 10 * n
    # rest of code
```